# How do I allow the user to pay via PayPal's REST API, but without them having to register a PayPal account?

Tags: paypal

This is my desired use case:

- I create a payment via PayPal's REST API.
- I give the user the payment's link, sent to me by PayPal, that the user follows.
- The user *chooses whether to pay via their PayPal account, stored credit card **or instantly via a credit card without registering***.
- I receive a confirmation.

I can do everything except the penultimate step: I only manage to succeed either:

- Allowing the user to pay via their existing PayPal account, or
- Allowing the user to pay via a credit card *they gave me the details of already*.

I don't want to know their credit card number. All I want is for them to pay any way they want, *via PayPal*, and then have a confirmation sent to me.

Is this possible?

If so, how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the new [REST API](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK) to do what you are mentioning.

To check it out, I would recommend trying sample/payments/CreatePaymentUsingPayPal.php.

Follow the Images shown below:
Open the Samples. Click on PayPal Account Payments `Execute button` {2nd Link}
[image: Open the Samples]
Use the URL to go to Paypal to pay
[image: Use the URL to go to Paypal to pay] 
This will open this default page. Notice the button Pay with Debit or Credit Card
[image: This will open this default page. Notice the button Pay with Debit or Credit Card]
Fill it up and enjoy
[image: Fill it up and enjoy]

Answer (score 0):

You can use PayPal Express Checkout to direct user from your site to PayPal site. After user completed their payment by using credit card (or PayPal account) on PayPal site, they will be back to your site automatically by your setting.

For more information about API, please refer to https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/gs_expresscheckout/

Comment: This is the classic API, but I wish to use the new REST API instead.