# Receive money from clients without asking them to create Paypal account

Tags: php, paypal

I created a merchant account in Paypal and I have a web site. I would like to get payment from my web site members without asking them to create Paypal accounts. I just want them redirected to a Paypal page with the total amount and my details, getting the payment through their credit card.

Which service do I have to use and how? Does anybody know a "for dummies" style documentation for this process? I am using PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please can you follow this answer. This should definitely help.

[How do I allow the user to pay via PayPal's REST API, but without them having to register a PayPal account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26731862/how-do-i-allow-the-user-to-pay-via-paypals-rest-api-but-without-them-having-to/26745163#26745163)

Answer (score 1):

All paypal checkout pages have an option for the customer to pay using their credit/debit card if they do not have a paypal account and don't want to create one.

Comment: No it seems it doesn't. I am using https://www.paypal.com/tr/cgi-bin/webscr address but It doesn't give an option of not having Paypal account. It brings only login or create account options